# How to get \AddToShipoutPicture* to place image at top of page?

Tags: graphics, wallpaper

I'd have a PDF image that I'd like to use as a background as follows:

- Scaled to width of the page
- Positioned at the top of the page such as it is flush with both upper corners
- The rest of the document should lay out as normal

The image does not cover the entire page. It's more like a banner.

I came up with the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
  \AddToShipoutPicture*{%
      \parbox[t][\paperheight][t]{\paperwidth}{%
           \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}
      }
  }
  The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dogs.
\end{document}
```

This almost works, except that the image is at the bottom of the page. I also tried wrapped `\parbox` at with `\put(0,0){...}` but that didn't help. If I replace `\includegraphics` with text, the text is rendered at the very bottom left of the page.

How do I get the image to appear flush with the top left corner instead?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic)'s internal positioning mechanisms. In this case, `\AtPageUpperLeft`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \raisebox{-\height}{%
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}%
    }%
  }
}
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.

\end{document}
```

Since the image would sit on the baseline (in general), `\AtPageUpperLeft` would actually place the image so it sits "above" the page. However, `\raisebox{-\height}` brings it down into view on the actual page.

Comment: That just seems rude! "Ok, let's make a frame. Here, good, looks fancy. Now, let's take this image and place it just outside that very frame so nothing of it is actually in the frame." Can you imagine how offended that frame now must be? :P

Comment: What does `\height` refer to?

Comment: @Roxy: `\height` in `\raisebox{<len>}{<stuff>}` refers to the height `<stuff>`. So, `-\height` will drop `<stuff>` by its height. So, where formerly the object's bottom was sitting on the baseline, it will not have its top touching the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your preamble

```
\usepackage[pscoord]{eso-pic}
```

This can go anywhere, preample or anywhere in your document, but before the first usage of the command (as in any programming environment, afaik)

```
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
    \put(0,0){%
        \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
            %           \vfill
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,%
            keepaspectratio]{../IMG/imagefilename.ext}%
            \vfill
}}}
```

And then in the document or in the `titlepage` environment, this

```
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}
```

Comment: if `pscoord` doesn't solve your case, try `textcoord` instead, cf. "Package Options" on p. 2 of the `eso-pic` package documentation (eso-pic v2.0h, dated 2018/04/12).

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but I'm really confused about the interaction between the `\put(0,0)`, `[b]` and `\vfill` at the end. Changing any of these results in the image going to the bottom again. Why is this? Also, I didn't actually need `pscoord`.

Comment: Good question. I hope someone strolling by can answer all of this. I'm really just struggling myself, you know.

Comment: True, since `pscoord` ist just the default.

Comment: According to the manual, `pscoord` uses a coordinate system with the origin (0, 0) in the lower left corner of the page - where you put your `parbox`. The `[b]` argument sets the anchor to the bottom of the `parbox`, while `\vfill` fills the vertical space on the page not occupied by the image. As `\vfill` is placed after the image, this moves the image to the top of the page. (The `texcoord` option for `eso-pic` would set the origin to the upper left corner of the page.)

Comment: @epR8GaYuh would textcoord move the image out of the page, because the anchor of the image is the lower left corner?

Comment: @thymaro Yes (I am not sure about the corner stuff, but for the reason that we put the anchor of box at the bottom), although the option is named `texcoord` ;) By the way: It should read `AddToShipoutPicture*{BackgroundPic}` instead of `\AddToshipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}`.

Comment: @Roxy: Please consider voting, in general, in support of answers that helped you most.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh ok thx for the answer. My BackgroundPic is a command, hence the backslash.

Comment: @thymaro Damn, missed that I added another typo to my correction. But it has to be `Shipout` instead of `shipout` as written in your version.

Comment: @epR8GaYuh huh, you're correct. Something must have gone wrong when copying the code. I'll have to go find it in my thesis to make sure I didn't accidentally change it there, too. Thanks for the catch.